# Why doesn't the @Value Spring annotation work in this class?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I have a very simple class in my Spring project, this is literally it:

```
@Component
public class Indicator {
    @Value("${indicator}")
    private String indicator;

    public String getIndicator() {
        return indicator;
    }
}
```

It doesn't work. The value returned from the get method is always null. I can't figure out why.

'indicator' is defined in my properties file:

indicator=dev

And, there are other properties in the same file which are read by my app in the exact same way in other places, which work!

How could this be?

Comment: Probably because you are doing `new Indicator()` instead of using the spring managed one. An `@Value` cannot be `null` and if no default value has been provided startup of the application would fail with an exception telling you so.

Comment: Add some information:  1. The name of your properties file.  2. If it is neither "application.properties" nor "application.yaml", did you configure an @PropertiesSource configuration class? 3. What is the path to your properties file within your project?

Comment: I need this value in a static initialization block. I'm not sure where I could put an Autowired property in this context. Is it possible?

Comment: Is there some command I could execute that would directly give me the value instead of relying on annotations?

Comment: How do you try to get value injected by spring in some static initialization block. Could you show some code?

Comment: You cannot get it in a static block as that is at classloading time, which is far before Spring has any change of setting the value.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the responses. I understand now that it's fundamentally impossible to access an autowired resource from outside of a Spring-managed component. I considered turning my class (which is a simple collection of date utilities) into such a component, but the idea of having to Autowire a utility class into everything that needs it (including JPA entities) doesn't appeal to me.

What I did instead is the same thing I've done dozens of other times in non-Spring projects; I just read the environment properties files in with a Properties object.